# jinja UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'length'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to shorten the length of a post on the posts page, similar how you would if your programming in wordpress codex snippet, but this is python and im using jinja here is my code

**Posts.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="posts-title text-center">Our Blog</h1>
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <div class="posts">

            {% for post in posts%}
                <div id="article-post" class="post">

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="container">

                        <h1 class="posts-title">  <a href ="{{ url_for('show', slug=post.slug) }}">  {{ post.title }} </a> </h1>
                        <p class="article-body">{{ post.body.length(200) }}</p>
                    <p>by: {{ post.author.username }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: What are you expecting `post.body.length(200)` to do, given that `post.body` is a unicode object (a string for that matter)? If you are trying to limit it to 200 characters, try `post.body[:200]` instead.

Comment: THANKS it worked, how did you know how to do that ?

Comment: Python strings don't have `length` method (though they do have `_len_` which should not be called directly, but with `len(string)`). Instead I've used Python's slicing syntax.

Comment: any documentation i can seek for future references, i never seen [:] being used before to shorten length